# Json: force conversion of an array with only one element to proper JS object

Tags: javascript, php, json

I use PHP arrays with numeric keys, but they don't go from 0 to n, but can be randomly chosen (it is a script for implementing schedule events which take some specific places in the schedule. They must be associated to the right place because there can be more than one on the same place; but some places can also be empty). Such arrays are converted to JS objects (maps) and it's OK. But, if an array contains accidentally only one item with key "0", it's converted to a JS array, because it IS actually a proper array. Therefore the result is not consistent.

```
$array1 = [2 => "something", 3 => "something"];
becomes:
array1 = { 2: "something", 3 : "something" }; (GOOD)
```

but

```
$array2 = [0 => "something"];
becomes:
array2 = ["something"]; (BAD)
```

How can I force a consistent conversion?

One idea would be to add a dummy key to each array to make it associative:

```
$array3 = [0 => "something", "forceMap" => true];
```

Any better idea?

Comment: I use json_encode() to do this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this site: https://www.php.net/json_encode you just have to use the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT parameter with the json_encode() function to do this:

```
$json = json_encode($yourObject, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
```